# Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected on ubuntu 21.04

Tags: gnome, google-chrome

i am using ubuntu 21.04.installed gnome shell extensions on chromium
i did ran **sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell** but still its showing me **Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected**

Comment: Showing you what? The question makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Chromium is packaged as a snap application. Snap applications are containerized (i.e., they run in a "sandbox"). That means that they have no unlimited access to the system resources.

One of the side effects is that the native host connector to have the operating system communicate with the Gnome Shell extensions website is not available to Chromium.

Perhaps that issue will be addressed one day, but in the mean time, you will need to workaround.

- There are several extensions that can be installed conveniently [from Ubuntu software](https://askubuntu.com/a/1063935/558158).
- Other extensions not available in Ubuntu software can be installed [manually](https://www.pragmaticlinux.com/2021/06/manually-install-a-gnome-shell-extension-from-a-zip-file/). This is somewhat more technical, but not that difficult. Once installed, they are automatically updated if you install the "Extensions" tool (`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs`).

Note that the problem will extend to Firefox soon, because starting from the forthcoming Ubuntu 21.10, also Firefox will be provided as a snap install.

Comment: Manual install did the trick for me on Ubuntu 21.10, thank you! Firefox being a snap package now was the info that I was missing before, too. Scoured so many askubuntu/stackoverflow questions before, but they all can't possibly work anymore, because of that.